# Configure multiple Jacoco reports for Sonarqube with Maven

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am building a SpringBoot/Maven project. Jacoco is configured to check coverage and creates 3 reports:

- from unit tests (surefire) target/jacoco.exec (xml: target/site/jacoco)
- from integration tests (failsafe) target/jacoco-it.exec (xml: target/site/jacoco-it)
- aggregate (jacoco-aggregate) target/jacoco-aggregate.exec (xml: target/site/jacoco-aggregate)

Without any additional configuration Sonarqube seems to create it's own aggregate:

```
[INFO] 13:14:27.153 Analysing C:\Users\code\dras-mt\target\jacoco-it.exec
[INFO] 13:14:27.248 Analysing C:\Users\code\dras-mt\target\jacoco.exec
[INFO] 13:14:27.414 Analysing C:\Users\code\dras-mt\target\sonar\jacoco-merged.exec
```

And it warns about deprecated use of properties:

```
[DEBUG] 13:14:27.000 Property 'sonar.junit.reportsPath' is deprecated and will be ignored, as property 'sonar.junit.reportPaths' is also set.
```

(they are not set via my pom.xml)

The problem with the generated report is, that Sonarqube seems to show the aggregated coverage but only counts the unit tests.

My question is how to get a consistent report (coverage matches count tests) and in best case how to export all 3 reports to Sonarqube (Sonarqube's own aggregate could be the 4th).

I tried to use property:

```
<properties>
    ....
    <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
        ${project.build.directory}/site/jacoco-aggregate/,${project.build.directory}/site/jacoco/,${project.build.directory}/site/jacoco-it/
    </sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
</properties>
```

But this property seems to be completely ignored (i tried also absolute and reletive paths and set via -D and also single path) - so log output (also using -X) does not change.
(first i tried this: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/coverage-test-data-importing-jacoco-coverage-report-in-xml-format/12151)

So how to correctly confige the sonar-maven-plugin (3.7.0.1746) to show the 3 reports?